# Logstash crashes as soon as it starts

Tags: docker, crash, logstash, docker-compose

As stated in the title, Logstash crashes as soon as it starts.
I'm running it through Docker.

This is my output:

```
logstash_1         | {:timestamp=>"2016-10-25T13:14:31.470000+0000", :message=>"Reading config file", :config_file=>"/etc/logstash/conf.d/logstash.conf", :level=>:debug, :file=>"logstash/config/loader.rb", :line=>"69", :method=>"local_config"}
logstash_1         | {:timestamp=>"2016-10-25T13:14:31.570000+0000", :message=>"Plugin not defined in namespace, checking for plugin file", :type=>"output", :name=>"stdout", :path=>"logstash/outputs/stdout", :level=>:debug, :file=>"logstash/plugin.rb", :line=>"86", :method=>"lookup"}
logstash_1         | {:timestamp=>"2016-10-25T13:14:31.584000+0000", :message=>"starting agent", :level=>:info, :file=>"logstash/agent.rb", :line=>"213", :method=>"execute"}
logstash_1         | {:timestamp=>"2016-10-25T13:14:31.585000+0000", :message=>"starting pipeline", :id=>"main", :level=>:info, :file=>"logstash/agent.rb", :line=>"487", :method=>"start_pipeline"}
logstash_1         | {:timestamp=>"2016-10-25T13:14:31.606000+0000", :message=>"Plugin not defined in namespace, checking for plugin file", :type=>"codec", :name=>"rubydebug", :path=>"logstash/codecs/rubydebug", :level=>:debug, :file=>"logstash/plugin.rb", :line=>"86", :method=>"lookup"}
logstash_1         | {:timestamp=>"2016-10-25T13:14:31.632000+0000", :message=>"config LogStash::Codecs::RubyDebug/@metadata = false", :level=>:debug, :file=>"logstash/config/mixin.rb", :line=>"154", :method=>"config_init"}
logstash_1         | {:timestamp=>"2016-10-25T13:14:31.789000+0000", :message=>"config LogStash::Outputs::Stdout/@codec = <LogStash::Codecs::RubyDebug metadata=>false>", :level=>:debug, :file=>"logstash/config/mixin.rb", :line=>"154", :method=>"config_init"}
logstash_1         | {:timestamp=>"2016-10-25T13:14:31.791000+0000", :message=>"config LogStash::Outputs::Stdout/@workers = 1", :level=>:debug, :file=>"logstash/config/mixin.rb", :line=>"154", :method=>"config_init"}
logstash_1         | {:timestamp=>"2016-10-25T13:14:31.796000+0000", :message=>"Will start workers for output", :worker_count=>1, :class=>"LogStash::Outputs::Stdout", :level=>:debug, :file=>"logstash/output_delegator.rb", :line=>"77", :method=>"register"}
logstash_1         | {:timestamp=>"2016-10-25T13:14:31.812000+0000", :message=>"Starting pipeline", :id=>"main", :pipeline_workers=>2, :batch_size=>125, :batch_delay=>5, :max_inflight=>250, :level=>:info, :file=>"logstash/pipeline.rb", :line=>"188", :method=>"start_workers"}
logstash_1         | {:timestamp=>"2016-10-25T13:14:31.816000+0000", :message=>"Pipeline main started", :file=>"logstash/agent.rb", :line=>"491", :method=>"start_pipeline"}
logstash_1         | {:timestamp=>"2016-10-25T13:14:31.826000+0000", :message=>"Input plugins stopped! Will shutdown filter/output workers.", :level=>:info, :file=>"logstash/pipeline.rb", :line=>"148", :method=>"run"}
logstash_1         | {:timestamp=>"2016-10-25T13:14:31.935000+0000", :message=>"Pushing flush onto pipeline", :level=>:debug, :file=>"logstash/pipeline.rb", :line=>"458", :method=>"flush"}
logstash_1         | {:timestamp=>"2016-10-25T13:14:31.942000+0000", :message=>"Pushing shutdown", :thread=>"#<Thread:0x6d334b22 run>", :level=>:debug, :file=>"logstash/pipeline.rb", :line=>"395", :method=>"shutdown_workers"}
logstash_1         | {:timestamp=>"2016-10-25T13:14:31.946000+0000", :message=>"Pushing shutdown", :thread=>"#<Thread:0x30e6a1db sleep>", :level=>:debug, :file=>"logstash/pipeline.rb", :line=>"395", :method=>"shutdown_workers"}
logstash_1         | {:timestamp=>"2016-10-25T13:14:31.957000+0000", :message=>"Shutdown waiting for worker thread #<Thread:0x6d334b22>", :level=>:debug, :file=>"logstash/pipeline.rb", :line=>"400", :method=>"shutdown_workers"}
logstash_1         | {:timestamp=>"2016-10-25T13:14:31.963000+0000", :message=>"Shutdown waiting for worker thread #<Thread:0x30e6a1db>", :level=>:debug, :file=>"logstash/pipeline.rb", :line=>"400", :method=>"shutdown_workers"}
logstash_1         | {:timestamp=>"2016-10-25T13:14:31.970000+0000", :message=>"closing output delegator", :klass=>"LogStash::Outputs::Stdout", :level=>:debug, :file=>"logstash/output_delegator.rb", :line=>"137", :method=>"do_close"}
logstash_1         | {:timestamp=>"2016-10-25T13:14:31.972000+0000", :message=>"closing", :plugin=>"LogStash::Outputs::Stdout", :level=>:debug, :file=>"logstash/plugin.rb", :line=>"37", :method=>"do_close"}
logstash_1         | {:timestamp=>"2016-10-25T13:14:31.976000+0000", :message=>"Pipeline main has been shutdown", :file=>"logstash/agent.rb", :line=>"491", :method=>"start_pipeline"}
logstash_1         | {:timestamp=>"2016-10-25T13:14:34.823000+0000", :message=>"stopping pipeline", :id=>"main", :file=>"logstash/agent.rb", :line=>"406", :method=>"shutdown_pipelines"}
logstash_1         | {:timestamp=>"2016-10-25T13:14:34.830000+0000", :message=>"Closing inputs", :level=>:info, :file=>"logstash/pipeline.rb", :line=>"384", :method=>"shutdown"}
logstash_1         | {:timestamp=>"2016-10-25T13:14:34.832000+0000", :message=>"Closed inputs", :level=>:info, :file=>"logstash/pipeline.rb", :line=>"386", :method=>"shutdown"}
```

This is my logstash.conf file:

```
input {

}

filter {

}

output {
    stdout {
        codec => rubydebug  # for debugging
    }
}
```

It checks out when I run `logstash -t logstash.conf` so it's not an issue with the config file.

What could the issue be?
cat'ing `meminfo` shows:

```
MemTotal:        3797716 kB
MemFree:          334368 kB
```

`top` shows:

```
top - 15:22:36 up 1 day,  1:42,  2 users,  load average: 0,52, 0,53, 0,80
Tasks: 298 total,   1 running, 297 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
%Cpu(s):  2,1 us,  2,4 sy,  0,0 ni, 94,4 id,  0,2 wa,  0,0 hi,  0,9 si,  0,0 st
KiB Mem :  3797716 total,   325552 free,  1956392 used,  1515772 buff/cache
KiB Swap:  4063228 total,  4059964 free,     3264 used.  1610224 avail Mem
```

Doesn't seem to be a hardware issue.
One curious thing is a log message from running elasticsearch:
`elasticsearch_1  | [2016-10-25 12:37:01,076][WARN ][bootstrap                ] unable to install syscall filter: seccomp unavailable: your kernel is buggy and you should upgrade`
but this shouldn't have any effect on how logstash is running, actually the elasticsearch container runs just fine.

EDIT:
`docker-compose.yaml` for ELK-stack:

```
##############
## ELK STACK
##############

version: '2'

services:
  elasticsearch:
    image: 'elasticsearch:latest'
    ports:
      - "xxxx:xxxx"
    networks:
      - net

  logstash:
    build: './logstash_image'
    links:
      - elasticsearch
    ports:
    #in1
      - "xxxx:xxxx"
    #in2
      - "xxxx:xxxx"
    #in3
      - "xxxx:xxxx"
    #in4
      - "xxxx:xxxx"
    #in5
      - "xxxx:xxxx"
    networks:
      - net
    # network_mode: host    # set up same network values as host (debug only)
# TODO: limit/rotate docker logs:
#       https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#/logopt
#       https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#logdriver

  kibana:
    image: 'kibana:latest'
    ports:
      - 'xxxx:xxxx'
    links:
      - elasticsearch
    volumes:
      - ./kibana.yml:/opt/kibana/config/kibana.yml
    networks:
      - net


networks:
  net:
    driver: bridge
    ipam:
      driver: default
      config:
      - subnet: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/xx
        ip_range: yyy.yyy.yyy.yyy/yy
        gateway: zzz.zzz.zzz.zzz
```

Comment: How is logstash configured in `docker-compose.yml`?

Comment: @EltonStoneman I've added it now to the question, had to hide some implementation-specific stuff but should be enough to figure out any issues.  The compose file goes through without issues and runs the containers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Logstash does not *crash*, it's simply exiting because your configuration file explicitly specifies an empty input source (`input {}`). The log pipeline does not have any kind of data source (by default it will at least have STDIN as data source), so it just exits.

**Note** that explicitly defining an empty input with `input {}` is **different** and not defining any input (in which case, Logstash will assume `input { stdin { type => stdin } }` as a default value and listen for data input on the STDIN stream).

This behaviour is defined in Logstash's help output (`logstash agent --help`) (emphasis mine):

> `-e CONFIG_STRING` - Use the given string as the configuration data. Same syntax as the config file. **If no input is specified, then the following is used as the default input**: `input { stdin { type => stdin } }` [...]

Comment: I only used the barebone `logstash.conf` that I provided as an example, I'm actually using a config with 5 input sources, 2 filters and 1 output. It seems that I did something wrong in the docker-compose rebuild so that my new configs were never copied over, thus the erroneous config was in place. Thanks for shedding some light on this and helping me troubleshoot.

Comment: By the way, how is using the `logstash agent` command different from just using `logstash` ie. `logstash -e foo`? Afaik `logstash agent` is the runtime used by logstash, but I can't find much documentation for it.